# SQL Queries Insert Error

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values on the table `ARTIST` that it is below but I keep getting the error :

```
INSERT INTO ARTIST VALUES (‘2DS’, ‘Dimitres Sergides’, to_date(‘19901231’,’YYYYMMDD’), to_date(‘19980212’,’YYYYMMDD’), ‘CYPRIOT’)
```

ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-00917: missing comma "

the table artist is below:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTIST
(
      A_id VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT PK_ARTIST PRIMARY KEY,
     Name VARCHAR(40),
     DOB DATE,
     DOD DATE,
     Nationality VARCHAR(30));
```

Do anyone know why I keep getting the error? is there something I don't see?

Comment: Don't tag three different database systems.

Comment: Are you using sql-server or orcale or mysql?

Comment: Looking into the error message `ORA-00917: missing comma "`  the SO is using oracle

Comment: sorry i use sql server!

Comment: i don't believe that you are using SQL-server   `ORA-00917` is a oracle error message.

Comment: don't know if the cause here, but you have weird quotation marks, like here they are different for the 2 params: `‘19901231’,’YYYYMMDD’` try using standard `'` or `"` instead

Comment: In general, just vote to close typo questions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sometime Oracle give misleading error. Here in this case `ORA-00917: missing comma` .. Which i felt little misleading.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like error lies with `‘` which is different than `'`. Use this:

```
INSERT INTO ARTIST
     VALUES ('2DS',
             'Dimitres Sergides',
             TO_DATE ('19901231', 'YYYYMMDD'),
             TO_DATE ('19980212', 'YYYYMMDD'),
             'CYPRIOT')
```